# Sublime Text 3 and LiveReload Google Chrome extension

Tags: sublimetext3, livereload

I downloaded new Sublime Text 3 and I can't get working [LiveReload Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei)

I know that it works for Sublime Text 2 but can I use it with ST3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently updated to work with Sublime Text 3. See [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/1u460e/livereload_replacement_for_sublimetext_3/) for some other recommendations.

Comment: Thank you too. I hope I will get new working tool. :P

Comment: @testerius Can you please unaccept this answer – it's no longer correct.

Answer (score 12):

They rewrote the plugin for ST3: 
"Have a look at devel version. Which is total rewrite of plugin, supporting SublimeText 3, plugins and much more." -ST2 ReadMe on GitHub

It is available from here:
https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2/tree/devel

Use your terminal to remove the existing LiveReload package and then clone the repo:

**Linux**

```
cd ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
rm -rf LiveReload
git clone -b devel https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2.git
```

**OSX**

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/
rm -rf LiveReload
git clone -b devel https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2.git LiveReload
```

Once installed, you will still need to enable the plugin in the command palette as described by @Nishait_Baig:

- open the Sublime Text command palette (while in Sublime Text type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> on Linux/Windows or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> on Mac)
- Type ***LiveReload: Enable/disable plugins*** and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Scroll down to ***Enable - SimpleReload*** and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

From @Allen:

> if you browse your webpage through the html file path, don't forget to check ***Allow access to file URLs*** in the chrome extension settings.

Comment: After installing this version, I still had to activate the SimpleReload plugin with the Command Palette. This works, as @Nishat Baig mentioned in another answer on this topic.

Comment: I Agree with @Christian

Comment: The Github repository is dead

Comment: The github repository has been deleted.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue.
I enabled the SimpleReload plugin in the Command Palette.

```
=> Ctrl+shift+p  
=> LiveReload: Enable/disable plugins  
=> Enable - SimpleReload
```

And it started working.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me. I didn't know livereload had these settings disabled by default!

Answer (score 2):

If you browse your webpage through the html file path, don't forget to check `Allow access to file URLs` in the chrome extension settings.

Comment: this was what finally did the trick for me Settings -> Extensions -> Allow access to file URLs

Answer (score 1):

LiveReload Sublime text3： 
https://github.com/Grafikart/ST3-LiveReload

But the usage seems to have changed:
Enable desired plug-ins via Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) add livereload.js to you html document.

Answer (score 0):

For permanently enabling it.
 **preferences -> Packge Settings -> LiveReload -> Settings - User**

Add:

{ 
    "enabled_plugins": [
        "SimpleRefresh"
    ]
}

Comment: Hello there. This doesn't seem to be working for me. Everything else works but I just can't get the plugin enabled by default!

Comment: Sorry about the double comment. I just realized changing the setting shows an updated menu entry after Ctrl+Shift+P in "enable/disable plugins" but it has no real effect until i actually click the thing in the menu.